# Redirect all URLs to a single page in the httpd.conf

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd.conf

I am looking for a way to redirect an entire website to one single domain. I want to do this in the `httpd.conf` file. For example the VirtualHost I have looks like:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx>
ServerName website.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/cgi-bin/
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/website
CustomLog logs/website/access_log combined
ErrorLog logs/website/error_log
Redirect / http://newwebsite.com
Redirect /xxx http://newwebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently the redirects above still keep the full URL.

So if I want to http://website.com/test/thispage.html I would redirect to http://newwebsite.com/test/thispage.html. I just want it to go to newwebsite.com and lose the rest.

So..

http://website.com/test/thispage.html

to

http://newwebsite.com

What do I need to add to the `httpd.conf` to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

As you have noticed Redirect catches all and sends the same URI to the target which is what you don't want, so you will use RedirectMatch, to match all possible requests, but not adding anything to the target url.

So you can just use:

RedirectMatch ^ http://newsite.example.com/

As a side note about mod_rewrite:
I certainly do not recommend mod_rewrite as recommended by others unless you really have a task at hand which requires the complexity only mod_rewrite can offer, and this is not the case.

Side note 2:
For examples it is better to use "example.com" domain name since it is not a valid domain and it is permanently reserved for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
Redirect / http://newwebiste.com
Redirect /xxx http://newwebiste.com
```

and add

```
RewriteRule ^ http://newwebsite.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I get an invalid command warning when restarting the httpd service. See below

Comment: Syntax error on line 1526 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: I think the apache server needs to be updated. The rewrite mod doesn't exist, which is why the whole thing was failing

Comment: Perhaps you just need to uncomment [LoadModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) in your http.conf, it is really strange to see an apache without mod_rewrite

Comment: Recommending mod_rewrite for simpleton redirections is not the way to go. This is very bad advice.